# generate Date and time with chance.js

Tags: javascript

Anyone knows how to generate a random date and time '03/01/1999 10:30:20' with chance.js. The following only generate date only.

```
chance.date({year: 2019, american: false, string: true});
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Chance.js has separate methods to generate time.

You can use `chance.hammertime();` for Unix time, `chance.hour()`, etc.

[See docs here](https://chancejs.com/time)

Then you can just combine the output in a template string together -

```
const fakeDateTime = `${date} ${hour}:${minute}:${second}`;
```