# Generate date and time between a given time frame

Tags: r, date, time, series

I want to generate a large series (say, 1,000) of date-time in "MM/DD/YYYY mm:ss" format between 12/01/2019 and 6/30/2020 but separated by irregular intervals (between successive observations), and then append the data as a new column to a dataframe of the same row length. The desired out should look like this:

```css
 id mem_id      phone     time  
  2    549 2023406636    12/01/2019 13:41
  2    549 2023406636    12/07/2019 02:45
  3    222 2023402289    12/25/2019 11:27
  3    222 2023402289    01/12/2020 08:30
  2    549 2023406636    01/14/2020 10:54
  3    222 2023402289    03/12/2020 12:34
```

I have reference the `timeDate` and `timeDate` packages (and [this earlier thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63324860/generate-date-and-time-with-chance-js)) but couldn't figure out how to do this. It will be very appreciated if someone could shed some lights on this.

Comment: You say "generate a series". How, randomly? Usually you already know the timestamps (and you may want to convert from one format to another), here you don't say where they are supposed to come from.

Comment: They could be anytime between the specified timeframe only with irregular intervals between successive observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be generate a sequence of 1 second interval between `start_date` and `end_date` and `sample` `n` values from it.

```
start_date <- as.POSIXct('2019-01-12', format = '%Y-%m-%d', tz = 'UTC')
end_date <- as.POSIXct('2020-06-30', format = '%Y-%m-%d', tz = 'UTC')
n <- 1000

date_Time <- sort(sample(seq(start_date, end_date, by = 'sec'), n))
head(date_Time)
#[1] "2019-01-12 18:48:49 UTC" "2019-01-14 04:38:40 UTC" "2019-01-14 06:00:24 UTC"
#[4] "2019-01-15 06:39:53 UTC" "2019-01-15 13:31:48 UTC" "2019-01-15 15:05:13 UTC"
```

If you need data in specific format, you can use `format` on `date_Time`

```
date_Time_format <- format(date_Time, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
head(date_Time_format)
#[1] "01/12/2019 18:48" "01/14/2019 04:38" "01/14/2019 06:00" "01/15/2019 06:39"
#[5] "01/15/2019 13:31" "01/15/2019 15:05"
```

Comment: That's really helpful and thanks so much for clarifying the formatting issue.